# why won't this populate my 'sku' column in my Grid.php

Tags: grid, products, column

I'm trying to figure out how to get my Collection to populate the 'sku' column of my Grid.PHP.

```
    protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('AdvancedStock')->__('Sku'),
        'filter' => false,
        'width' => '100px',
        'sortable' => false
    ));
            return parent::_prepareColumns();
}


    protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $productId = $this->getProduct()->getId();
    $query = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');
    $query->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns(array('sku')) //,'SUM(row_total)'
        ->group(array('sku'));
    $this->setCollection($query);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

[image]

I'm expecting that 1 column to have something, am I way off?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here

```
 $query->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns(array('sku')) //,'SUM(row_total)'
        ->group(array('sku'));
```

to

```
$query->getSelect()->getSelect()->columns(
                array(
                    'my_total'  => SUM(main_table.row_total))
                )
            ) ->group('sku');
```

**if it is not works  then ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS) to myquery after ->getselect() and ->columns('*') end of query**

For getting `row total of of` sum you need to `add it columns at prepareColumns function`

```
  $this->addColumn('my_total', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('AdvancedStock')->__('Product all Total'),
        'filter' => true,// for filter make true
        'width' => '100px',
        'sortable' => true
    ));
```